# Architecture recommendation for GCP Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am implementing a gmail client in our application. The application is based on multi-tenant architecture having multiple databases and differentiated by subdomain. I have implement Gmail APIs for required features, and working on handling incoming mails.

I have implemented GCP Pub/Sub with one topic and one subscription, and watch the gmail account everytime an user authenticates. Things get messy when the same email is authenticated in multiple tenants. It needs to look into each of the tenants if the email matches and update accordingly. Also in case an user logs out, every tenant needs to be checked before stopping the sync.

I have thought to create a topic per tenant dynamically. And each topic would have a subscription pointing to the subdomain of that tenant. I know there is a quota limit of 10000 per project. It would take forever to reach the limit though. Have anybody tried it? Any other recommendations you think of?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a subscription per tenant, then allow each tenant to check to see whether they can process a message or not?

Comment: Hi @PatrickMagee, I could make a subscription per tenant. Since emails are watched on topics, whenever changes happens in the email, the publisher publishes to all the subscriptions. So lets say there are 200 tenants, it will be published to 200 tenants. And there is a quota on subcription throughput as well. Have you tried the approach? I thought if I create topics based on tenants, it will be only published on particular tenants.

Comment: It looks like the Subscription Quota per topic (and per project for that matter) is 10k.  with a throughput of basically 2 G/s. If you never anticipate having more then 2G/s or more then 10,000 tenants, I would just go with this approach.  Even if you eventually will get there, chances are you will  be in a better place to determine exactly what you need, and it will likely be a very different solution then what you are currently implementing https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas